# could not login to asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Hello I am new to asp.net,and I am developing an asp.net web application project from scrap in visual studio using IIS server locally.When I run it locally,the login page will open and when I try to login,it displays like 
"Oops ..Something went wrong please contact support." where all login user information and all data are stored in sql server and I have configured to connect to sql server To access datatable in web.config file like:

I could login with the same userid and password in web application published but I couldn't login locally.
Could someone help me out with this,thanks in advance

Comment: Is the server returning an error? Check DevTools or the `response` object in  `function OnErrorCall(response)`.

Comment: _"Oops ..Something went wrong please contact support"_ is not an error message we can do anything about. First obtain the actual exception, then show what you found about that.

Comment: @CodeCasteryeah actually that message displays on error a call
                                                                                                            
       success: OnSuccessCall,
        error:      OnErrorCall

Comment: @CodeCaster Onsuccesscall  it wil redirects to an url: WebNav_Login,you can check the code login.js in file attached.and this url is defined in page WebNavigation.js,where i have attached that file also

Comment: The JS is irrelevant. What you need is to obtain the actual error.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether Forms Authentication is enabled or not in IIS where your application is running.

Run Inetmgr -> locate your application -> Select Authentication -> you will get Form Authentication - Enable it.

If you application running in IIS express locally, check this same setting there also.

Comment: hey ankur thanks for the reply,the application is running in IIS express and there is no settings provided to enable Forms Authentication so I enabled the Form Authentication in Inetmgr.and getting the same message displayed while trying to login

Comment: @ADyson, It is available in IIS.  Please verify in IIS console.